# Is there a way to generate dynamic excel data validation lists based on source table?

Tags: excel, validation, dynamic

I have two workbooks, one is the source of validation data (Source workbook) and second is for filling in values (Order workbook).

In the source workbook Sheet1 I have a table with data like this (there can be an expanded amount of paper and grams combinations)

[image]

In order workbook (where actual order if filled in) I use references to source workbook using data validations combined with named tables.

In source workbook I need Grams data validation lists based on the Paper entered for each of the rows, here is an example with NovaPress Gloss we see only three selections:
[image]

with ArcticSilk+ we see 5:

[image]

These drop lists were hard coded to show what I need to fulfil.

To sum up I need dynamic data validation lists based on other cell value which is the same value as in the source workbook table for each of the entered orders (I, II, II etc.).

All I managed to find was this rather nice answer [Advanced Dynamic Validation Lists in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22262573/advanced-dynamic-validation-lists-in-excel) but it used intermediate table for "dynamic" list and in my case I need to have many independent lists.

Can this be achieved using just excel functionality or some VBA code is needed? All help is appreciated

Comment: from my understanding, **INDIRECT** does not work if the referenced workbook is closed. This means you will need to use the direct link which is not dynamic. I would normally including the table of validation list in the same workbook so I can use INDIRECT to create dynamic validation list.

Comment: Hi, the referenced workoob (source) will be auto opened so I can use data from it in my data validation lists. Issue is I do not know how to implement such functionality I described in my question.

Comment: I only know how to set up the dynamic dropdown list for one line. Your desired outcome is for any amount of rows which seems hardly achievable.

Comment: If you can make a separate list for each product's GSM range, and have these lists in the same workbook as the order form, then there is a way to make the dynamic list within the order table for each line of product. Let me know if the above conditions can be met and you are happy to see a solution based on that.

Comment: Thanks for a reply. Yes it would be possible to have source data split up into many tables based on paper name. Preferably source tables would be in a Source workbook but if that is not possible we might settle having it in the Order workbook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming within the same workbook, you have the following two **structured reference tables**:

1. `GSM` - This is the table that holds the GSM data for each paper product in the following structure:

[image: Table - GSM]

2. `Order` - This is the table that you select the GSM from a dynamic data validation list for each paper product:

[image: Table - Order]

Firstly, you need to set up a **named range** called `List_GSM` using the following formula:

```
=XLOOKUP(Order[@Product],GSM[#Headers],GSM)
```

[image: Named Range - List_GSM]

Please note, if your version of Excel cannot use **XLOOKUP**, you can use a combination of **INDEX + MATCH** to fetch the range of GSM for each product in a similar way.

```
=INDEX(GSM,,MATCH(Order[@Product],GSM[#Headers],0))
```

Secondly, set up the drop-down list using the named range `List_GSM` in the GSM column of the `Order` table:
[image: Data Validation - List]

You can set it up in the first empty cell and then drag it down to apply to all cells in that column.

The drop-down list will look up the product name in the first column and return the corresponding GSM list from the `GSM` table.

[image: Test 1 - A]
[image: Test 2 - D]

The key to this methodology is to make sure the `Order` table's product names are the same as the headers of the `GSM` table. You can either use power query to pivot your source table or manually set up the `GSM` table so that the product names are in the header.

One obvious advantage of using **structured reference table** is that you can update your source table with new product data. The drop-down list in the `Order` table will be updated dynamically. See the below example:

[image: Test 3 - E]

Let me know if you have any questions :)

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed response, works as described. One thing I'll have to try and solve is the whitespace entries. Some papers might have 3 selections while others 30.

Comment: @MisterWhite, I guess this is another limitation of this methodology that you cannot hide the blanks as you cannot have a table with different row numbers for each column. If you happen to come across a better solution, please share it here. Cheers.

Comment: In the end managed to solve "empty" rows with an offset function in the lines of:
`=OFFSET(<Index function provided by you>,0,0,COUNTA(<index function provided by you>))` . First parameter of OFFSET could be refined to make more optimized but this still works.

Comment: @Mister White thanks for letting me know. If you are using Excel 365, you can use the LET function to simplify the OFFSET function by declaring the INDEX function as X and then use X in the OFFSET function.