# Dynamic Data Validation List based on an Input (no VBA)

Tags: excel, excel-2019

I need your help.

I have the following table:

| ARTICLENR | UNIT | NAME |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100002000000100 | 1300 | 0-SK |
| 100004000000200 | 1300 | 0-SK |
| 101001000000100 | 1100 | 0-kg |
| 101001000000100 | 1101 | 1-H-SG-kg |
| 101001000000100 | 1102 | 2-F-kg |
| 101001000000100 | 1103 | 3-F-Stk |
| 101001000000101 | 1100 | 0-kg |
| 101001000000101 | 1101 | 1-H-SG-kg |
| 101001000000101 | 1102 | 2-F-kg |

and so on...

This table is stored in a Worksheet, called (Units).

Now in a different Worksheet, called (Calculator), I would like to enter an article number in one cell and then have excel automatically generate a dropdown list of available units for that corresponding article number in different cell.

I have excel 2019 so I can't really use UNIQUE or FILTER...

Appreciate your input.

Thank you

Comment: search for dependant drop down - there are quite a lot of answers on SO

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to generate dynamic excel data validation lists based on source table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66517490/is-there-a-way-to-generate-dynamic-excel-data-validation-lists-based-on-source-t)

Comment: the solution is clever, but I can't have my data stored in a table similar to the GSM table in the mentioned example. I have 300,000 rows of data and around 100,000 article number specifically.